# What does 00+ mean in the Intel x86 assembly manual?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

In the Intel documentation manuals, I see references to `00+` multiple places, but no definition. What is this `00+` instruction/opcode?

Comment: Example? I can't remember running into it and I could not find it searching the PDFs I have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Referred to an instruction/opcode, it means it's supported by 8086 or later processors.

Instruction's introductory processor code:

```
* 00: 8086
* 01: 80186
* 02: 80286
* 03: 80386
* 04: 80486
* P1 (05): Pentium (1)
* PX (06): Pentium with MMX
* PP (07): Pentium Pro
* P2 (08): Pentium II
* P3 (09): Pentium III
* P4 (10): Pentium 4
* C1 (11): Core (1)
* C2 (12): Core 2
* C7 (13): Core i7
* IT (99): Itanium (only geek editions)
```

> 1. If the processor marking is a range (e.g., 03-04), it means that the
>      instruction is unsupported in later
>      processors.
> 2. XX+ means the instruction is supported in any later processors and also in 64-bit mode, if the next row doesn't
>      explicitly say otherwise.

Comment: It would be great if you linked to the source of that information.

Answer (score -1):

According to a [very useful x86 OP code listing](http://ref.x86asm.net/geek.html#x00) its an ADD instruction(the one byte variant)